# Rename folders/directories based on metadata with R

Tags: r, directory, metadata, rename

I have a question that concerns renaming folders based on information in a metadataframe. Underneath you will find my directory structure and an exmaple of the .information of the metadata.

Metadataframe:

| date | Sample_name | S_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021_05_20 | V_3_4 | S1 |
| 2021_05_20 | V_9_4 | S2 |
| 2021_05_20 | H_13_5 | S3 |

Directory structure:

```
main Directory
        |
        |___ 2021_metadata.txt
        |___ Experiment
                ├── D0
                   ├── Weather
                           |__ S1
                           |__ S2
                           
                │  └── Temperature
                           |__ S1
                           |__ S2
                └── D1
                   ├── Weather
                           |__ S1
                           |__ S2
                           |__ S3
                   └── Temperature
```

I'm not really familiar with R, but I think it is possible to manually rename folders with the file.rename() function of R. However, what I would like is to make a code that is able to recognize the name of the folder and rename it into the corresponding sample_name found in the metadatafile. For example the folder name is S1 and change it into V_3_4?

Is someone able to help me with this?
Thank you in advance

Edit

```
name_file <- "./20210325_metadata_r_test_1.txt"

Metadataframe <- read.delim(name_file)


dirs <- list.dirs(path = "./experiment/", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

if(any(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)){
    for(dir in dirs[which(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)]){
        shell(paste("move", dir, Metadataframe$Sample_name[which(Metadataframe$S_number == dir)]))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list.dirs('/path', recursive = F, full.names = F)` to find the current directory names (e.g. S1, S2, ...). Then you can change the names using `system(paste('mv', old_dir, new_dir))`

Example:

```
main_dir
└── experiment
    └── D0
        ├── temperature
        │   ├── S1
        │   └── S2
        └── weather
            ├── S1
            └── S2
```

```
Metadataframe <- data.frame(Sample_name = c("V_3_4", "V_9_4", "H_13_5"), S_number = c("S1", "S2", "S3"))

setwd("~/main_dir/experiment/D0/temperature/")
dirs <- list.dirs('./', recursive = F, full.names = F)
if(any(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)){
    for(dir in dirs[which(dirs %in% Metadataframe$S_number)]){
        system(paste("mv", dir, Metadataframe$Sample_name[which(Metadataframe$S_number == dir)]))
    }
}
```

```
main_dir
└── experiment
    └── D0
        ├── temperature
        │   ├── V_3_4
        │   └── V_9_4
        └── weather
            ├── S1
            └── S2
```

You could put all of that into a for loop to do all your folders.

Edit: To change all the directories:

```
main_dir
└── experiment
    ├── D0
    │   ├── temperature
    │   │   ├── S1
    │   │   └── S2
    │   └── weather
    │       ├── S1
    │       └── S2
    └── D1
        ├── temperature
        │   ├── S1
        │   ├── S2
        │   └── S3
        └── weather
            ├── S1
            ├── S2
            └── S3
```

```
Metadataframe <- data.frame(Sample_name = c("V_3_4", "V_9_4", "H_13_5"), S_number = c("S1", "S2", "S3"))

dirs <- list.dirs('~/main_dir', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
if(any(grepl(paste(Metadataframe$S_number, collapse = "|"), dirs))){
    for(dir in dirs[grep(paste(Metadataframe$S_number, collapse = "|"), dirs)]){
        dir_path <- sub("S[0-9]+", "", dir)
        sample <- sub(dir_path, "", dir)
        new_path <- paste0(dir_path, Metadataframe$Sample_name[which(Metadataframe$S_number == sample)])
        system(paste("mv", dir, new_path))
    }
}
```

```
main_dir
└── experiment
    ├── D0
    │   ├── temperature
    │   │   ├── V_3_4
    │   │   └── V_9_4
    │   └── weather
    │       ├── V_3_4
    │       └── V_9_4
    └── D1
        ├── temperature
        │   ├── H_13_5
        │   ├── V_3_4
        │   └── V_9_4
        └── weather
            ├── H_13_5
            ├── V_3_4
            └── V_9_4
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to run your code, but it seems that it does not change my folders from S1 to V_3_4 etc. There is no error, but it does not do anything. Another question that I have is whether it is also possible to just do the list of dirs from the main directory so you get the whole list of directories. Can you than skip the for loop? I edited my question with my piece of code

Comment: What OS are you using? My solution assumed it was Unix/Linux based. If you are on Windows, instead of `system` use `shell` and inside `shell` instead of `mv` the windows equivalent is `move`. And yes, as you say you can avoid the for loop, but you would have to set the `full.names` parameter to `TRUE`.

Comment: Ah I see. I used indeed windows as OS. I still have one question. I edited my question with the code that I wrote. If I use your code the way you showed it it works and my folders are renamed the way that I want. However, if I try to do it the way that I want with list.dir of the whole map, so without for loop, it does not work. The code runs, but the folders do not change. What am I doing wrong? Could you also show me how I can use a for loop to loop over all the maps with your code?